# My solution to LeetCode SQL question No.1174. Immediate Food Delivery II with CTE and Window function always shows syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Link to this question is here:
https://leetcode.com/problems/immediate-food-delivery-ii/

My solution is the following, with CTE and Window function. I tried in mysql and oracle but neither works and both show syntax error. Can't figure out why.

```
with rank as
(
    select
        customer_id,
        order_date,
        customer_pref_delivery_date,
        rank() over (partition by customer_id order by order_date asc) as rnk
    from 
        delivery
)
select 
    round(avg(f),2) as immediate_percentage
from
    (select
         case 
            when order_date = customer_pref_delivery_date 
            then 1 else 0 
         end as f
     from 
         rank
     where 
         rnk = 1) as first_orders;
```

Oracle error:

> Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Mysql error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank as
>   (select
>   customer_id,
>   order_date,
>   customer_pref_delivery_date,
>   rank() ove' at line 3

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: Hi it says "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" in Oracle. and a long one in MySQL i pasted in the question.

Comment: Oracle does not support using `AS` for table aliases. And MySQL only recently added support for window functions, you are probably using an outdated version

Comment: I removed column aliases in oracle and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For oracle error; you have to remove the "AS" before **first_orders**. Because "AS" cannot come after "FROM" keyword.

```
    SELECT ROUND (AVG (F), 2) AS IMMEDIATE_PERCENTAGE
  FROM (SELECT CASE
                  WHEN ORDER_DATE = CUSTOMER_PREF_DELIVERY_DATE THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
               END
                  AS F
          FROM RANK
         WHERE RNK = 1) FIRST_ORDERS;
```